# Filter then copy and paste values to new Excel tab

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use an autofilter to filter unique values, then copy and paste these values to a new Excel tab.

The macro stops working at this line of code.

```
Sheets(sht).Range("A1:A" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
  CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"), Unique:=True
```

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "data"

'change filter column in the following code
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:AY" & last)
'set last column

Sheets(sht).Range("A1:A" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
  CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"), Unique:=True

For Each x In Range([CA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "CA").End(xlUp))
    With rng
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=x.Value
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

        Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = x.Value
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 15

    End With
Next x

' Turn off filter
Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

With Application
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does "wouldn't run" mean precisely?

Comment: Seems like incomplete code to me. Is that all of the code ?Can you explain what exactly it does ?

Comment: Perhaps you need to define a name your source Range. you can define a name that dynamically adjusts the size to the last row containing data and use it:
Sheets(sht).Range("Defined_name").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"), Unique:=True

Comment: If i'm not wrong advanced filter only let you copy to the same sheet, if you are calling the macro from a different sheet, you are not qualifying the paste range, so it goes to the activesheet which AdvancedFilter doesn't like because is no the same as the filter sheet.

Comment: I have added in the full line of code above.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion i think:

1. You are missing an `End Sub` at the end of your code.
2. `CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"),` you dont mention the sheet name just the range.

Comment: i have added in the full code in my above post. Is my copytorange:=range("CA1") linked to Sheets(sht). ?

Comment: No, replace `CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"), Unique:=True` with `CopyToRange:=.Range("CA1"), Unique:=True`

Answer (score 0):

it is Working !!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim x As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim last As Long
Dim sht As String

'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
sht = "data"

'change filter column in the following code
last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:AY" & last)
'set last column

Sheets(sht).Range("A1:A" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("CA1"), Unique:=True


End Sub
```

Comment: Did it work because the data sheet was active when you ran the code? I can't see a difference between your code & the original.

Comment: I have added in the full line of code above, it doesn't work for me somehow.